# How to create SourceCode only nuget packages for WPF environments

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget

We have some code in our own "framework" that we want to share between all of our projects.
But for some reasons we don´t want that special code to be in it´s own assembly.
Rather we want a NuGet package that adds the code as a `C#` file.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@attilah/source-code-only-nuget-packages-8f34a8fb4738) that describes how to do that, and than I used [the mentioned GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/attilah/fd3e71f03fd258c496179e0200c57b0b) to create my package.

Everything worked great until I used it in a WPF project.  As soon as I add a `UserControl` to the project I get a build error that the code from the NuGet package can´t be found.

I created [a sample project](https://github.com/rzlsoftware/CodeOnlyNugetPackageTest) to show the error.
The screenshots below show code from that sample.

Here I added the `source code only` NuGet package and built the solution.
[image: Building the code without a Usercontrol]

Here I added an empty `UserControl`. Now the code is breaking.
[image: broken reference to nuget package code]

What do I have to change to make that also working when using WPF?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would packaging [source generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/#example-scenarios-that-can-benefit-from-source-generators) be a good solution to your problem?

Comment: You say framework code but your project is in core. Make the package in core and try to re apply it in your project.

Comment: @nalka I just read several articles and tried some samples but I can´t figure out how that could solve my problem.

Comment: @XAMlMAX by Framework code I mean: A piece of code that I want to reuse in several different projects.
By `core` do you mean `.net core`? 
I don´t want to change the .net SDK or the Targetframework to something else than `netstandard` because I need the code in `net5`, `net5-windows` as well as `net472`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help at [manuelroemer/Nullable#20](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable/issues/20) I could find a solution to the problem.
The solution is described at [microsoft/CsWin32#7](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32/issues/7)

The referencing WPF project has to add the following property in the project:

```xml
<IncludePackageReferencesDuringMarkupCompilation>true</IncludePackageReferencesDuringMarkupCompilation>
```